# What is corrupting the stack of this multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stack-overflow

This script produces a fibonacci spiral which starts off in the centre and branches outward. Although the output is correct, i get an error message saying:

"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'fibArr' was corrupted."

I've tried reducing fibCount by 1, but this caused the central number to be 0 which I dont want.

```
int fibFunc(int);


int main() {
    //--setting variables
    const int rowCount = 5, colCount = 5;
    const int fibCount = rowCount * colCount - 1;
    static int f; 
    int i, j;


    //--creating  grid
    int grid[rowCount][colCount] = { 0 };

    //Create fibArr
    f = fibCount;
    int fibArr[fibCount];

    while (f >= 0) {
        fibArr[f] = fibFunc(f);
        f--;
    }


    //directions settings
    enum direction {
        DOWN, RIGHT, UP, LEFT
    } d = DOWN;

    //spiral loop
    int R = 0, C = 0; //R for row, C for column
        f = fibCount;
        while (f >= 0) {

            grid[R][C] = fibArr[f];

            f--;


            if (d == DOWN) {
                if (grid[R+1][C] == 0)
                    R++;
                else d = RIGHT;
            }


            if (d == RIGHT) {
                if (grid[R][C+1] == 0)
                    C++;

                else d = UP;
            }

            if (d == UP) {
                if (grid[R-1][C] == 0)
                    R--;
                else d = LEFT;
            }

            if (d == LEFT) {
                if (grid[R][C-1] == 0)
                    C--;
                else {
                    d = DOWN;
                    R++;
                } 
            }
        }

    printFib(fibArr, fibCount); 
    for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
            cout << setw(7) << grid[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause>nul");
}   

int fibFunc(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibFunc(n - 1) + fibFunc(n - 2);
}
```

Output

```
75025     55     89    144    233

46368     34      1      2    377

28657     21      1      3    610

17711     13      8      5    987

10946   6765   4181   2584   1597
```

Comment: hint: array indexing is from 0 to size - 1

Comment: fibCount=colCount * rowCount -1

Comment: Also note that your code relies on a non-standard compiler extension, *variable length arrays (VLAs)*.

Comment: @LogomonicLearning -- How is that going to fix the issue?  If `fibCount` is some number, then `fibArr[f]` where `f == fibCount` is an out-of-bounds access.

Answer (score 0):

As juanchopanza pointed out, array indexing is from 0 to size - 1.

```
const int rowCount = 5, colCount = 5;
const int fibCount = rowCount * colCount - 1;
```

This would result in:

```
fibCount = 24 = ( 5 * 5 ) - 1;
```

Further down, at your while loop:

```
int R = 0, C = 0; //R for row, C for column
f = fibCount;
while (f >= 0) {

    grid[R][C] = fibArr[f]; // f = 24; size = 24;

    ...

}
```

Here you take a value from your array fibArray with the index of 24. Last index would be 23.

---

Change this to:

```
const int fibCount = rowCount * colCount;
```

Then before your while loop:

```
f = fibCount - 1;
```

---

Besides that I would use a single dimensional array like this:

```
int rows = 5, cols = 5;
char* tst = new char[ rows * cols ];

int select_row = 2;
int select_col = 3;

tst[ select_row * cols + select_col ] = 65;
char c = tst[ select_row * cols + select_col ];

delete[] tst;
```

Comment: What's wrong with `std::array`? Why use a C-style array at all? And why heap allocate it? And if you *do* heap allocate it, why not stuff it into a smart pointer (naked `delete`'s are an abomination in modern C++)?

Comment: Nothing wrong with std::array, where did I mention that? Doesn't have to be on the heap either.

Comment: you didn't say it was bad, just you didn't use it ;)

Comment: Usually I use a third-party library for an array. Did it like this for faster and easier jumping around the array. Should be on the stack and then take a pointer to it.

Comment: @ Tim it is always nice to see other implementations of the same code so your input is much appreciated.

Comment: @LogomonicLearning You did think of the second _f = fibCount_, right?

Comment: @JesperJuhl ok, a smartpointer is maybe better but abomination I wouldn't say. Not using a naked pointers could be called lazy. Indeed I see the pro's of smartpointers. Don't see a real problem in naked pointers.

Comment: @LogomonicLearning Since I am not allowed to post a comment at your question: `if (d == DOWN) { if (grid[R+1][C] == 0) R++; else d = RIGHT; }`, in the while loop the conditions are always `else` resulting in all if statements calling the `else`, then substract one from `f`. Again only `else` is executed. Basically said, nothing is done.